Finding Instantaneous value of alternating sources using phasors
Phasors are the vectors which would rotate about origin in anticlockwise direction. They are generally used to study about phase angles of varying quantities like alternating current, voltage,etc. In my book I read that the instantaneous value that quantity represented in phasor form is given by the vertical component of that quantity.But I couldn't understand why is it so

All explained, with animations, in the Wikipedia article Phasor.
